How to let Terraform infer dependency of a resource on creation of a private endpoint without `depends_on`?
I want to create a container inside an Azure storage account via Terraform. The storage account has public access disabled, thus before creating the container, a private endpoint must be created in a vnet/subnet I have access to. I've learned that it's generally not recommended to use depends_on because it can lead to too conversative behavior in Terraform and also some unexpected results.
Is there a way to let Terraform infer the dependency of the container upon the private endpoint without using depends_on?
